# Why are interactions always mediated via bosons (as opposed to fermions)?

Tags: particle-physics, forces, interactions, bosons, carrier-particles

Weak, Strong and electromagnetic force are mediated via bosons. I've come across the Walecka-model where the exchange particles are $\sigma$ and $\omega$ mesons; bosons again. why are interactions always mediated via bosons (not fermions)?

Comment: I just found my answer...
https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81414/

Comment: That's true, I also had the same question, but does one interpret something like triangle diagrams? Isn't a part of the interaction mediated via fermions?