# What are the differences among bosons, force-carrier particles and mediators?

Tags: forces, resource-recommendations, bosons, carrier-particles

1. Are all bosons force-carrier particles?
2. What is the difference between these three concept?
3. Where can I find a comprehensive & detailed information about these particles?
4. How it can be related with thermodynamics and (quantum) statistical mechanics?

Comment: The most significant property of boson is that the amplitude of a boson to exist at certain state increases by $\sqrt{n+1}$ where $n$ is the number of bosons that are already existing in that certain state. You can't find this property in fermions & this is responsible for the Exclusion Principle for fermions.

Comment: No offence intended, but your question is very broad, as reflected perhaps in the textbooks you have listed.  If you start by asking _what is a boson?_, I think you need to do some basic research, before you make the stretch to the rest of your points about quantum statistics.

Comment: @count_to_10. You're right. The original questions would be "Could you suggest some resources that can shape my research?" Because googling bosons and properties not giving much information about it.

Comment: Have I missed something? Or are resource recommendations are [now no longer on topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/7039/)? (I realize that I argued in that thread for making them off-topic, but it's not a terribly well-received answer at the moment).

Comment: I've edited the question. If it's fits the rules can anyone open it for answers.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81414/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Any basic course in statistical mechanics can potentially cover Fermi-Dirac and Bose-Einstein statistics; see for example [this introductory course](http://www.spms.ntu.edu.sg/PAP/courseware/statmech.pdf) that Google brought up, which begins defining things at a relatively low-level.

If you are at an advanced level and have already had a basic course in statistical mechanics but want to quickly brush up and tackle more advanced problems, [Jos Thijssen's  Advanced Statistical Mechanics notes](http://ocw.tudelft.nl/fileadmin/ocw/courses/AdvancedStatisticalMechanics/res00013/overview.pdf) are great. The discussion that perhaps you are looking for is on page 33: why the permutation operator must commute with the Hamiltonian, have eigenvalues $\pm 1$, and then how we have to choose one sign and propagate it across all of our particles to be truly consistent because we can swap e.g. the first and third particles in states A,B,C by swapping AB, BC, then AB again, leading to the conclusion that the sign from flipping AC must be equal to the sign from flipping BC (the sign from AB cancels itself). A similar argument then says that this is also the sign from flipping AB.

If you don't yet know quantum mechanics, you can probably get this from Griffiths' textbook *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*, which is the bog-standard reference book for teaching undergraduates QM. He has also written an *Introduction to Elementary Particles* which will presumably be somewhat overkill but might answer your question well enough.

Comment: Yes, I was checking that course right now. But I've also need more detail information about bosons and its quantum mechanical properties. 
https://www.uni-muenster.de/Physik.AP/Demokritov/en/Forschen/Forschungsschwerpunkte/mBECwabaf.html like in here but in more detail and more technical.

Comment: @ErbilŞilik I added a couple more references that might have your more-detailed information.